# Function not defined, although its been defined... Going Insane

Tags: python

So I am quite new to python and have been working on this assignment for a week now on and off and can't quite get it to run correctly. I am now getting errors that tell me the function get_in_code is not defined although I've defined it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
SENTINEL = 'XXX'
DAY_CHARGE = 1500.00
#Define get_days
        def get_days():
            good_data = False
            while not good_data:
                try:
                    n_days = int(input("Please enter the number of days you stayed: "))
                except ValueError:
                    print("Error, Bad Data")
                else:
                    if n_days > 0:
                    good_data = True
                else:
                    print("This is bad data, please re enter data")
            return n_days

        #define get_cost(p)
        def get_cost():
            cost = float(input("Please enter the cost for the procedures: "))
                while cost < 0:
                    print("Procedure cost cant be negative: ")
                    cost = float(input("Please enter the cost for the procedures: "))
                return cost

        #define med cost
        def med_cost():
            med_cost = float(input("Enter the cost of your medicine: "))
                while med_cost < 0:
                    print("Medicine cost cant be negative: ")
                    med_cost = float(input("Enter the cost of your medicine: "))
                return med_cost
        #Find day cost
        def find_day_cost(in_code, n_days):
            day_cost = n_days * DAY_CHARGE
            if in_code == 'ZH':
                p_day_cost = day_cost * 0.20
                in_day_cost = day_cost *0.80
            elif in_code == 'HH':
                p_day_cost = day_cost * 0.10
                in_day_cost = day_cost * 0.90
            elif in_code == 'CH':
                p_day_cost = day_cost * 0.25
                in_day_cost = day_cost * 0.75
            else:
                p_day_cost = day_cost
                in_day_cost = 0
                return p_day_cost, in_day_cost

        #find procedure cost
        def find_proc_cost(in_code, cost):
            if in_code == 'ZH':
                p_proc_cost = 0
                in_proc_cost = cost
            elif in_code == 'HH':
                p_proc_cost = cost * 0.10
                in_proc_cost = cost * 0.90
            elif in_code == 'CH':
                p_proc_cost = cost * 0.50
                in_proc_cost = cost * 0.50
            else:
                p_proc_cost = cost
                in_proc_cost = 0
            return p_proc_cost, in_proc_cost

        #find medicine cost
        def find_med_cost(in_code, med_cost):
            if in_code == 'ZH':
                p_med_cost = 0
                in_med_cost = med_cost
            elif in_code == 'HH':
                p_med_cost = med_cost * 0.10
                in_med_cost = med_cost * 0.90
            elif in_code == 'CH':
                p_med_cost = med_cost * 0.50
                in_med_cost = med_cost * 0.50
            else:
                p_med_cost = med_cost
                in_med_cost = 0
                return p_med_cost, in_med_cost

       #Display pat_info
        def display_pat_info(pat_name, in_name):
            print("City Hospital - Patient Invoice")
            print("Patient Name: ", pat_name)
            print("Insurance: ", in_name)

        #display day cost
        def display_day_cost(p_day_cost, in_day_cost):
            print("Patient Day Cost: ", p_day_cost,"\tInsurance Day Cost: ", in_day_cost)

        #display procedure cost
        def display_proc_cost(p_proc_cost, in_proc_cost):
            print("Patient Procedure Cost: ", p_proc_cost, "\tInsurance Procedure Cost: ",   in_proc_cost)

        #display medicine cost
        def display_med_cost(p_med_cost, in_med_cost):
            print("Patient Medicine Cost: ", p_med_cost, "\tInsurce Medicine Cost: ", in_med_cost)

        #Display totals
        def display_totals(total_pat, total_in):
            print("Total Billed To Patient: ", total_pat, "\tTotal Billed To Insurance: ",   total_in, "\tTotal Bill: ", (total_pat + total_in))

        #display day_totals
        def display_day_totals(total_zip, total_happy, total_cheap, total_pat):
            print("City Hospital - End Of Day Billing Report")
            print("Total Dollar Amount Billed Today: ",        total_zip+total_happy+total_cheap+total_pat)
            print("Total Billed To Zippy Healthcare: ", total_zip)
            print("Total Billed To Happy Healthcare: ", total_happy)
            print("Total Billed To Cheap Healthcare: ", total_cheap)
            print("Total Billed To Uninsured: ", total_pat)

            #display day_counts()
            def display_day_counts(zip_count, happy_count, cheap_count, no_in_count):
            print("The total amount of Zippy Healthcare patients is: ", zip_count)
            print("The total amount of Happy Healthcare patients is: ", happy_count)
            print("The total amount of Cheap Healthcare patients is: ", cheap_count)
            print("The total amount of Uninsured patients is: ", no_in_count)
#def main 
def main():

    #Counters and accumulators
    total_zip= 0.00
    total_cheap= 0.00
    total_happy= 0.00
    total_pat= 0.00
    zip_count= 0
    cheap_count= 0
    happy_count= 0
    no_in_count= 0
    total_in = 0

    #Open file
    try:
        Pat_File = open('PatientBill.txt', 'w')
    except ValueError:
        print("*****ERROR***** - Corrupt File")
    else:
        file_exist = True

    #Priming read
    pat_name = input("Please enter the patients name: (XXX to stop program)")

    #Processing loop
    while pat_name != SENTINEL:
        #Input data 
        in_code = get_in_code()
        num_days = get_days()
        proc_cost = get_cost()
        med_cost = med_cost()

        #find each cost
        pat_day, insure_day = find_day_cost(in_code, num_days)
        pat_proc, insure_proc = find_proc_cost(in_code, proc_cost)
        pat_med, insure_med = find_med_cost(in_code, med_cost)

        #update accumulators and totals
        total_pat += pat_day + pat_proc + pat_med
        if in_code == 'ZH':
            zip_count += 1
            total_zip += in_day_cost + in_proc_cost + in_med_cost
            in_name = 'Zippy Healthcare'
        elif in_code == 'HH':
            happy_count += 1
            total_happy += in_day_cost + in_proc_cost + in_med_cost
            in_name = 'Happy Healthcare'
        elif in_code == 'CH':
            cheap_count += 1
            total_cheap += in_day_cost + in_proc_cost + in_med_cost
            in_name = 'Cheap Healthcare'
        else:
            no_in_count += 1
            in_name = 'Uninsured'
            total_in = total_zip + total_happy + total_cheap
        #displays patients invoice
        display_pat_info(pat_name,in_name)
        display_day_cost(pat_day, insure_day)
        display_proc_cost(pat_proc, insure_proc)
        display_med_cost(pat_med, insure_med)
        display_totals(pat_day + pat_proc + pat_med, insure_day + insure_proc +   insure_med)

        #Write output to file
        if file_exist:
            Pat_File.write(pat_name, pat_day+pat_med+pat_proc )

        #Get next patients name
        pat_name = input("Please enter the patients name: (XXX to stop program)")
        #Close the output file
        if file_exist:
            Pat_File.close()

        #display the accumlators and totals
        display_day_totals(total_zip, total_happy, total_cheap, total_pat)
        display_day_counts(zip_count,happy_count,cheap_count,no_in_count)
        #define get_in_code
        def get_in_code():
            in_code = input("Please enter one of the insurance codes, ZH, CH, HH, XX")
        while in_code not in ('ZH', 'HH', 'CH', 'XX'):
            print("***Please enter a proper insurance code***")
            in_code = input("Please enter one of the insurance codes, ZH, CH, HH, XX")
        return in_code

main()
```

Comment: Hi. Please correct your indentation first. If your code is correctly written here it means that all the code you have after `def main` is not inside the function.

Comment: Trying to shrink the code example towards the minimum still showing the effect also may help to find the cause and has the side effect that nobody is bored by scrolling through non-essential stuff.

Comment: Take a deep breath. Sometimes when you are knee-deep in a project nothing seems to work anymore. But when you take a step back and really evaluate what you are doing things will get clear again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Python is a interpreted language. You need to define function prior to its usage. Just move a function definitions at the top of a file.

The problem is also with indentation. You're defining your methods inside `while`, just after a `return` statement. Actual functions aren't defined at all - interpreter doesn't reach those lines.

Besides, the code is "dirty". Split the code into separate classes/modules. Create well defined areas of responsibility, that would improve the code and it'll be easier to work with it.

Comment: I thought it didn't exactly matter where functions where written as I've completed other assignment having written them after. I did change it and it ended up running, but now its telling me the variable total_pat that i defined as 0.00 is not defined... It just seems to never end haha

Comment: You need to pay attention to indentation. Please format your code in the question properly.

Comment: I have it properly indented on sublime its just switching it over here thats throwing it off, sorry this is my first post. Any help for quick formatting, this was using the 4 space technique

Comment: Each block of indentation is a 4 spaces block. In other words code inside try/except block must be intended with 4 more spaces than the try/except etc.

Comment: I believe that should work now, still can't figure out the variable total_pat not being defined now

Comment: I have to go in and redefine the variables before i use them, its not recognized the section of variables I've defined

Comment: If youre indentation is correct you're defining functions inside while loop, just after a return statement - basically the rest of the code is dead.

Comment: would I have to implement a break statement to stop the while loop?

Comment: so i have gotten all the way to the second to last line of code without error until it gives me total_zip is not defined... even though its already been used earlier

Comment: As I suggested in the answer, split the code into separated classes/modules. Replacing return with break wouldn't fix the problem of "not well structurized code".

Comment: Doing this for a class assignment and was given certain instructions not to use modules as a challenge, trying to keep it to functions for now